# Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I am trying to send some data from Node JS to MySQL using "mysql" module downloaded from NPM.

```
connection.beginTransaction(function(err) {
        if (err) { throw err }
        connection.query(sq, function (error, result) {
              if (error) {
            //return connection.rollback(function() {
            throw err
          //})
          } else {
            console.log('data is inserted ... ' + new Date())
          }
        })
```

**My Query i.e. sq is some thing like that..**

```
INSERT INTO archlb_sales(fiscalYear, fiscalQuarterID, fiscalPeriodID, fiscalWeekID, geo, theater, area, operation, region, country, salesAgen
tName, emailID, arch, technology, subTechnology, tms3, productFamily, scms, totalSales, agentType, salesAgentnumber, softBookingsNet) values ('
2017', '2017Q1', '201701', '2017014', 'Americas', 'Americas-MISCL2', 'Americas-MISCL3', 'Americas-MISCL4', 'Americas-MISCL5', 'UNKNOWN', 'G2C A
djustment Agent', 'UNKNOWN' , 'Collaboration' , 'Collaboration','CLOUD SW' , 'CLD-AUDIO-SW' , 'CWAU', 'OTHER' , -205, 'TEAM AGENT', 'UNKNOWN' ,
 '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE totalSales = totalSales + -205;

INSERT INTO archlb_sales(fiscalYear, fiscalQuarterID, fiscalPeriodID, fiscalWeekID, geo, theater, area, operation, region, country, sal
esAgentName, emailID, arch, technology, subTechnology, tms3, productFamily, scms, totalSales, agentType, salesAgentnumber, softBookingsNet) val
ues ('2017', '2017Q1', '201701', '2017014', 'Americas', 'Americas-MISCL2', 'Americas-MISCL3', 'Americas-MISCL4', 'Americas-MISCL5', 'UNKNOWN',
'G2C Adjustment Agent', 'UNKNOWN' , 'Collaboration' , 'Collaboration','CLOUD SW' , 'CLD-AUDIO-SW' , 'CWAUCC', 'OTHER' , -123, 'TEAM AGENT', 'UN
KNOWN' , '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE totalSales = totalSales + -123;
```

The values of those variables are read from a text file, which are come correctly

MySQL gives the following error.

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the ri
ght syntax to use near \'INSERT INTO archlb_sales(fiscalYear, fiscalQuarterID, fiscalPeriodID, fiscalWeek\' at line 3
```

This is the table schema:

[image]

Comment: Can you post archlb_sales schema ? Are you sure that "fiscalWeekID" column  is striclty defined with these capitals ? (ID)

Comment: Can you post 'line 3'?  Exactly, rather than 'something like that'.

Comment: Maybe you are adding string into an integer field or something wrong according to datatype of columns..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to execute multiple SQL statements in one query, which is disabled unless you explicitly set the [`multipleStatements`](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options) option.